# No .so file after compiling with R SHLIB

Tags: r, fortran

So I wanted to compile my fortran subroutine to be able to use it in R. However I do not get an .so file only a .dll file. Is there maybe a problem with the paths? Or is this supposed to happen.

```
C:\BCT_Work>R CMD SHLIB draw_JU.f95
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gfortran    -O2  -mtune=generic -c  draw_JU.f95 -o draw_JU.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gfortran -shared -s -static-libgcc -o draw_JU.dll tmp.def draw_JU.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
```

Comment: That is normal for R on Windows.

Comment: But could I use the .dll instead of the .so to call my fortran subroutine in r

Comment: Yes, R will even expect a .dll file. See `.Platform$dynlib.ext`.

Comment: Ah yes I see now. Thanks a lot

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions. Your file suffix .f95 suggests you are not even using Fortran 90, but at least 95, so why using the specific version tag?